# Discrete analogue of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, reference-request

What kind of sequences $(a_n)\subset\mathbb{R}$ are expressible as the difference of two increasing sequences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of them. Define $b_1 = a_1$, $c_1 = 0$ and
$$b_{n + 1} = \begin{cases}b_n & a_{n + 1} \le a_{n} \\ b_n + a_{n + 1} - a_n & a_{n + 1} > a_n\end{cases}$$
$$c_{n + 1} = \begin{cases}c_n + a_n - a_{n + 1} & a_{n + 1} \le a_{n} \\ c_n  & a_{n + 1} > a_n\end{cases}$$
for $n > 0$. It is obvious that $b_n$ and $c_n$ are increasing and induction shows $a_n = b_n - c_n$.

Comment: Nice one, thanks.